# Smooth brush destroys my mesh

Tags: sculpting

So i'm sculpting and, sometimes, specially after i made a big change in the surface with any other brush, the smooth brush completely destroys the geometry that was there. This only happens after i've set dynotopo and changed the mesh, and if i turn it off, it stills creates the same problem.
Every now and then if i enlarge the radius of the brush, it fixes it, but usually i have to take out any hard edge or lower a big bump that i made before and that seemed to have caused it. The weird thing is that it acts like that for the whole mesh and not just specific parts, and that sometimes it only happens when using my graphic tablet(as in the gif), but other times with both the tablet and the mouse.

[image]

Comment: Check your normals and could there be another layer of verticies behind the mesh we can see in your video? Try turning down the strength of the Smooth brush. Let us know how you get on.

Comment: This is really silly but, turns out, my pen tablet has the option to swith from 'add' to 'substract', to essentially do the opposite of what the brush does, whenerver this happened was because i had it in 'substract' mode, i didn't realize this because in previous versions of Blender it 'shift' to smooth always smoothed stuff, not anymore it seems :p.

Comment: please add that as an answer so other can find it and well done on working out what the issue was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out, my pen tablet has the option to switch from *Add* to *Substract*, to do the opposite of what the brush was doing.

Whenever this happened was because I had it in *substract* mode, I didn't realize this because, in previous versions of Blender, <kbd>Shift</kbd> to smooth always smoothed stuff, but not anymore it seems.

Other person with similar problem: my tablet lists it as "pen or eraser" mode

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. For me pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> toggles between add/subtract for as long as I hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd>. Alternatively, you can also click the `+` or `-` in the top toolbar to switch between add/subtract smooth if <kbd>CTRL</kbd> doesn't work.

[image]